# What is an alternative screen recorder for Zoom Meetings?

Tags: video, screen-recording, screenshot, zoom

Have you tried to record your screen using by Zoom?
It is recording into very small and good quality video file.
I know the news about Zoom and wanna record my screen (even if I'm not making meeting) with another application which can record as small as Zoom and at least with same quality.

If you know how Zoom can record like this please share but the most important thins is the alternative screen recorder like Zoom?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you explain your requirements for those who never used Zoom (for good reasons)? They still might have the right thing for you. Also include on what OS the software must run – and how much you'd be willing to pay if it comes to paid solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Zoom has extremely good quality for the file size.  If you wanted to record with something else at higher size/quality, you could recompress it to be similar to Zoom afterwards by using the open source / free program ffmpeg.  Here's an example command:

`ffmpeg -i "source-file.mp4" -c:v libx264 -g 120 -r 8 -preset veryslow -b:v 300k "smaller-file.mp4"`

In the above, `-preset veryslow` makes the encode take longer but gives higher quality for the size.  The `300k` could be replaced with `200k` if you want an even smaller video file but with less quality.  This command gave me a good looking 100 second video which was only 3.8MB.

Answer (score 1):

OBS (https://obsproject.com/) is what I'd use. It can capture anything, it's free, open source, and can also output in the format of your choice. There are several guides online on how to use OBS to capture (e.g.https://www.techtarget.com/searchunifiedcommunications/answer/How-do-you-record-Zoom-meetings-using-OBS ), but the main steps are:

- Add a new source
- Select "Display capture"
- Move over the Zoom/Teams/Whatever meeting to the selected display
- Start capturing.

Answer (score 0):

There is vBrick recorder that works very well with Zoom for recording . Adding it as a participant seems to be enough to get it recording

Answer (score 0):

Flashback recorder is another option I liked using. Link: https://www.flashbackrecorder.com/express/